# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, email, reporting-services, error-reporting

I am making a report problem link on my website and I want it to email me the last address they were on before clicking on the report link. I know/think you use     $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  but I dont know how to put that in the mail code?So how would you write that here is my mail code with out it.

```
Mail("email@email.com", "Subject", "Message");
echo "Report Sent";
```

Comment: referers are unreliable. many browsers don't include it for privacy reasons, and others include forged/faked ones.

Comment: @MarcB Do you know how I would get something link that to work then?

Comment: There's nothing you can do for that... You still can use it, but it some case you won't have anything.

Comment: embed the address of the page in the url you pass to the problem reporter, eg. `http://example.com/problem.php?url=http://example.com/page_you_are_on.php`

Comment: @MarcB Where would I embed it to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message should be a variable that you can put information in:

```
$message = "Error report: <p>Last site visited: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}</p>....";

mail("email@email.com", "Subject", $message);
```

Note that the `HTTP_REFERER` bit is placed within {} in the string.  That's to force it to extrapolate the value (I don't like string concatenation).

Also note that, as has been said above, there's no guarantee that the REFERER will have the right value, or any value at all.

Comment: How would go about reporting this without using the refer style?

Comment: You could send the value to PHP asynchronously using JavaScript.  JS has the current location/url value in `document.URL`

Comment: Do you want the address of the CURRENT url they're at when they click the report button, or the PREVIOUS url?  If they found a page from Google, would you want to capture that?

Comment: What I am trying to get it to do is that if someone finds a error on my website I would want them to click on the link to report problem and then it would send me the address of the last part of the website they were at when they clicked on that link.

Comment: I guess it would be the CURRENT address

Comment: In that case, I recommend a different design.  You're not guaranteed that a user will report an error immediately after encountering it.  For detectable system errors (like, not being able to connect to the db), the error should be logged and sent automatically to you behind the scenes.  For something a user should report, have them fill out a form that asks for the url and a description of the problem

Comment: Ok,Thanks do you know what browsers dont support REFFER cause it is working exactly how it is supposed to in safari and google chrome at the moment?

Comment: I do not.  It's one of those things that has a *chance* to be missing/spoofed/wrong, so it's not good to use for critical functionality.  It's up to you to weigh whether error reporting is critical.

Comment: No problem.  I hope I was actually helpful. ;)

Comment: Anonymizing proxies often have an option to take out referers.

Answer (score 0):

Beside everything that has been told about http referers that can be sniffed, anonymizing proxies and so on, relying on the HTTP_REFERER is not a good programming standard.

Instead, if you have, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/application/client.php
```

Where users can click on

```
http://www.example.com/application/report_problem.php
```

Just pass the "...client.php" string to the "...report_problem.php" report problem handler you will create.

It's easy to pass the "originating" page link to the "report_problem", and can be done like this:

```
<?php
    // pages where you will append the "problem link"

    // $this_page holds an "url encoded" version of the request uri ( e.g. /application/client.php )
    $this_page = rawurlencode ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
?>
<a href="report_problem.php?originating_page=<?=$this_page;?>">Report problem</a>
```

Then, in the "report_problem.php" code:

```
<?php
     // report_problem.php

     $originating_page = ( array_key_exists ( 'originating_page', $_GET ) && ! empty ( $_GET['originating_page'] ) ? rawurldecode ( $_GET['originating_page'] ) : null;

     if ( ! empty ( $originating_page ) ) {
              $message = 'Error report: <p>Last site visited: ' . $originating_page . '</p>....';
              mail("email@email.com", "Subject", $message);
     }
     else mail("email@email.com", "Subject", "Problem from unkown page");
 ?>
```